# Find the OSGI bundle that exports a package?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

How do I find the bundle that exports a package?

I am using felix and I have a string like "com.test", how do I know which bundle exports that package?

I don't want to use PackageAdmin as it has been deprecated, and I don't really want to get the Export-Package header for each bundle and parse it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do this programmatically, not at the Gogo shell ... at least I'll assume that from wording of your question.

There is no real way to say "which bundle" exports a given package since there can be many bundles exporting any given package and that package can be in use from many bundles by many bundles. If you have a specific bundle and you want to know which bundle provides package `com.test` to it, you can get the importing bundle's wiring `Bundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class)` and then use `BundleWiring.getRequiredWires()` to get the providers of all of the bundle's dependencies.

From there you just need to find the wire of `osgi.wiring.package` namespace for the package you want, then the provider of that wire will be a `BundleCapability` of a `BundleRevision` of the bundle you are interested in.

Comment: This is basically what I was looking for. It's a shame I have to go through all bundles and check this though. I was hoping for a method on the framework that says, here's a package, which bundle satisfies it? Given that this is what the framework is doing behind the scenes when it has to resolve dependencies anyway. But anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

A quick solution is to iterate over the bundles, list the id and the export package header.

```
g! each (bundles) { echo ($it bundleId) (($it headers) get Export-Package) }
```

Note that you need to put spaces around the `{` and `}`! This prints for each bundle, its id and its Export-Package header. You can put this in a cmd:

```
g! exports= { each (bundles) { echo ($it bundleId) (($it headers) get Export-Package) } }
```

You can then use it easier with `grep`:

```
g! exports | grep webconsole
12 org.apache.felix.webconsole;version="3.3.0";uses:="javax.servlet,javax.servlet.http,org.osgi.framework",org.apache.felix.webconsole.bundleinfo;version="1.0.0";uses:="org.osgi.framework",org.apache.felix.webconsole.i18n;version="1.0.0";uses:="org.osgi.framework"
true
```

The official command for exported packages is `inspect`

```
g! inspect cap osgi.wiring.package
```

However, the output is very messy and hard to grep. However, if you know the package name then you can ask (deprecated) Package Admin.

```
g! r=servicereference org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin
....
g! pa=service $r
org.apache.felix.framework.PackageAdminImpl@2c7b40e3
g! $pa exportedpackages org.osgi.framework
org.osgi.framework; version=1.10.0
org.osgi.framework; version=1.9.0
org.osgi.framework; version=1.10.0
org.osgi.framework; version=1.9.0
g! each ($pa exportedpackages org.osgi.framework) { $it exportingbundle  }
0|Active     |    0|org.apache.felix.framework (0.1.0.SNAPSHOT)
```

Unfortunately, the Package Admin methods are overloaded and Gogo picks the first one that matches, otherwise it would be a lot easier :-(

If you have the set of bundles then the `bnd` command line can be useful. You can install it [here](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/wiki/Install-bnd-on-the-command-line).

You can then do:

```
$ bnd find -e "com.example*" jars/*.jar
```

or

```
$ bnd grep -e "com.example*" jars/*.jar
```

Comment: Putting this into the Felix OSGi console results in an error:                                                            
                                                                          
osgi> each (bundles) { echo ($it bundleId) (($it headers) get Export-Package) }                                                                               
gogo: IllegalArgumentException: Cannot coerce each(String, Closure) to any of [(CommandSession, Collection, Function)]

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:
exports | grep com.test ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I wanted to do this programmatically

Answer (score 3):

Recent versions of the Apache Felix OSGi console include a "dependency finder" plugin which lists the bundle(s) that export a given package or class. There are some screenshots at http://www.6dlabs.com/blog/dklco/2012-05-04/new-cq-55-dependency-finder (which mention CQ5 but the plugin does not depend on that).

That's useful at the admin level, and if you need to find that out in code you could have a look at that plugin's source code, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-3045